# Question on the motivation of Information Geometry

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, information-geometry

In the Preface of 'Methods of Information Geometry':

We consider the set, $S$, of normal distributions $P(x; \mu, \sigma) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\exp \left \{ - \dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right \}$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

So this means that if we specify $\mu,\sigma$,we determine a particular normal distribution. Hence the set of all possible $(\mu, \sigma)$ can be viewed as a 2-dimensional manifold, which has $(\mu, \sigma)$ as a coordinate.

My question is the statement that follows this: HOWEVER, this is not a Euclidean space, but rather a Riemannian space with a metric that naturally follows from underlying properties of probability distribution.

What does this mean? Can someone please explain it more gently? (And can some illustrations be made available for this?)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One can put a Euclidean metric metric on the space of $(\mu, \sigma)$, but the question is whether this is a natural or meaningful thing to do. Why not put a Euclidean metric on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$, for example?

Information geometry gives one answer to the question of what is a natural metric on a smooth family of probability distributions, and it gives an answer which has very strong invariance properties, i.e. does not depend on the metric structure on the state space. In fact, Chentsov's theorem says that the Fisher-Rao metric is essentially the only metric with these invariance properties (under certain assumptions). It is therefore regarded as canonical, i.e. arising only from the structure of the statistical model. Information geometry then explores the degree to which statistical algorithms correspond to the geometrical structures on the manifold of probability distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot, but David MacKay might be able to give you some insight into the first half.  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HrRNqb5C-b0 skip to 13:54.  David explains how to test multiple theories to explain data where each theory is a Gaussian with mean and variance specified by mu and sigma.  He explains why one might want to do that and does a really nice visual walkthrough.  I'm assuming that being able to redefine into Riemann space allows for some mathematical shortcuts, but I'm no expert in that part!